# how to check each letter in a string and do some action, in Python

Tags: python, string

So I was messing around in python, and developed a problem.
I start out with a string like the following:

```
a = "1523467aa252aaa98a892a8198aa818a18238aa82938a"
```

For every number, you have to add it to a `sum` variable.Also, with every encounter of a letter, the index iterator must move back 2. My program keeps crashing at `isinstance()`. This is the code I have so far:

```
def sum():
    a = '93752aaa746a27a1754aa90a93aaaaa238a44a75aa08750912738a8461a8759383aa328a4a4935903a6a55503605350'
    z = 0
    for i in a:
        if isinstance(a[i], int):
            z = z + a[i]
        elif isinstance(a[i], str):
            a = a[:i] + a[(i+1):]
            i = i - 2
            continue
     print z
     return z
sum()
```

Comment: `i` is the character, not the index. So just use `i`, not `a[i]`.

Comment: All the elements of `a` are strings, so `isinstance(i, int)` will always be false.

Comment: Thanks ! How would I fix the code to remove the 'a' char?

Comment: If you want to loop through indexes, you can use `for i in range(0, len(a)):`.

Comment: also `sum` already is a built-in, cannot use that as your own function.

Comment: You can also use `for i, char in enumerate(a):`

Comment: Why do you need to remove the non-numeric characters from `a`. Based on the snippet you provided, this function is purely meant to return the sum of all of the digits in `a`. The value of `a` will get discarded upon function exit anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This part is not doing what you think:

```
for i in a:
    if isinstance(a[i], int):
```

Since `i` is an iterator, there is no need to use `a[i]`, it will confuse Python.

Also, since `a` is a string, no element of it will be an `int`, they will all be `string`.  You want something like this:

```
for i in a:
    if i.isdigit():
        z += int(i)
```

***EDIT:***  removing elements of an iterable while iterating over it is a common problem on SO, I would recommend creating a new string with only the elements you wan to keep:

```
z = 0
b = ''
for i in a:
    if i.isdigit():
        z += int(i)
        b += str(i)

a = b    # set a back to b so the "original string" is set to a string with all non-numeric characters removed.
```

Comment: @Samuel Don't change your original code. It will make Will's answer look out of context.

Comment: No xD I meant the code I'm using. I'll let the question remain the same.

Comment: @Samuel Edited to include removing chars.  Check out docs for more on the "removing items from iterable while iterating" problem.  GLHF

Comment: Wow !  Your code looks pretty good ! But what about moving the index iterator back 2? Sorry, thats the real challenge lol.

Comment: @Samuel  Moving the iterator back 2 positions works fine in C-like languages, but in Python it gets very messy.  see here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/3553/common-pitfalls/949/changing-the-sequence-you-are-iterating-over#t=201609012029271551283.  Basically, in order to do what you're trying to do, you would have to use a while loop: `i = 0` then `while i < len(a):`.  You could then use `a[i]` to access your string, but you'd have to rewrite the whole loop to account for this difference.  I usually use `for i in thing:` and use temporary containers for processing.

Comment: "`i` is an iterator" - I don't think so.

Comment: I've changed the code to use `range()` and just go with `a[i]` to allow for using I as an iterator.

Comment: @StefanPochmann  You appear to be correct, I had no idea.  What's the term for `i` in this?

Comment: @Will "string" or "character"?

Comment: @Will maybe the "loop variable".

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your code. You don't seem to understand how `for... in` loops work, but @Will already addressed that problem in his answer. Furthermore, you have a misunderstanding of how `isinstance()` works. As the numbers are characters of a string, when you iterate over that string each character will also be a (one-length) string. `isinstance(a[i], int)` will fail for every character regardless of whether or not it can be converted to an `int`. What you actually want to do is just try converting each character to an `int` and adding it to the total. If it works, great, and if not just catch the exception and keep on going. You don't need to worry about non-numeric characters because when each one raises a `ValueError` it will simply be ignored and the next character in the string will be processed.

```
string = '93752aaa746a27a1754aa90a93aaaaa238a44a75aa08750912738a8461a8759383aa328a4a4935903a6a55503605350'

def sum_(string):
    total = 0
    for c in string:
        try:
            total += int(c)
        except ValueError:
            pass
     return total

sum_(string)
```

Furthermore, this function is equivalent to the following one-liners:

```
sum(int(c) for c in string if c.isdigit())
```

Or the functional style...

```
sum(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, string)))
```

Comment: What about the part of the script that removes the non-numeric characters from `a`?

Comment: Thanks !
I know it's not the best code in the world, as I'm much more experienced in Javascript and am still learning some python through experience (plus I kinda threw this code together xD ).  @Barmar made a good point about the script not moving the index counter back my two.

Comment: Moving the counter back by two is itself a mistake which relates to your lack of understanding of `for... in` loops. There is no "counter" here. `c` literally takes on the value of each character in the string. At the end of each loop cycle, it will automatically take on the value of the next character.

Comment: Should I use `range()` to get the index of `a` then?

Comment: @Samuel You don't need the index of `a`! You're overcomplicating the problem.

Comment: But I'm not just removing the letter! I need to move the iterator back by two as stated in the original ^

Comment: No, that was not the original question. You added that information to the question long after @Will and I answered it. In future scenarios like this one, just ask a new question.

Comment: Ok. I will :) Anyhow... Any idea?